# JQUERY and AJAX Pagination and Calling Data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am facing the following problem, I have a page of products with ajax pagination where users is able to select products in a form, the selected products save their id values in an array, but my problem is when the user goes to page 2 then he go back to page 1 he is able to choose the same product where I need to be the array ids unique, where user is able to select only the product 1 time even if he goes to page 2 or 3 and come back to previous pages

my ajax code:

```
$(".pageNumber").on("click",function(){

        pageID = this.id;

        var data_string = 'pageID='+pageID;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loadData.php",
        data: { "pageId" : pageID, "catid" : catid, "subid" : subid, "filter" : filter, "view" : view_type , "items" : itemArrayList},
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $(".pageNumber").removeClass("number-page-active");
            $("#"+pageID).addClass("number-page-active");
            $("#results1").hide();
            $("#results").html(result);
            console.log(result);
            if ($(".number-page-active").attr('id') == 1) {
            $('#sub1').attr("style","display:none") ;
        }
             if ($(".number-page-active").attr('id') != 1) {
            $('#sub1').attr("style","display:block") ;
        }
         if ($(".number-page-active").attr('id') == <?php echo $pageLast ?>) {
            $('#add1').attr("style","display:none") ;
        }   
             if ($(".number-page-active").attr('id') != <?php echo $pageLast ?>) {
            $('#add1').attr("style","display:block") ;
        }   

        }
    });
```

The list of selected products are saved in array as follow:

```
    $("#quotationSubmit").on("click",function(){
        console.log(itemArrayList);
        $("#itemListArray").val(itemArrayList);
    });
    var itemSelected = 0;
    itemArrayList = [];
    function image(divId) {
        if (itemSelected < 0) {
            itemSelected = 0;
        }
        var idDiv = 1;
        for (idDiv; idDiv <= 100; idDiv++) {       
            var divDivId = "" + idDiv;
            var divDivId0 = "" + idDiv;
            if (divDivId === divId || divDivId0 === divId) {
                break;
            }
        }


        if ($("#quotation-form").css("display") === "block") {
            if ($("#" + idDiv).hasClass("selected-div") === true || $("#" + 
            idDiv).hasClass("selected-div")) {
                $("#" + idDiv).removeClass("selected-div");
                $("#" + idDiv).removeClass("selected-div");
                itemSelected--;
                index = $.inArray(divId,itemArrayList);
                itemArrayList.splice(index,1);
                console.log(itemArrayList);
            } else {

                $("#" + idDiv).addClass("selected-div");
                $("#" + idDiv).addClass("selected-div");
                itemSelected++;
                itemArrayList.push(divId);
                console.log(itemArrayList);

            }

            if (itemSelected === 0) {
                document.getElementById("quotationText").innerHTML = "Please Select an item";
            } else {
                if (itemSelected === 1) {
                    document.getElementById("quotationText").innerHTML = "You have 1 item Selected";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("quotationText").innerHTML = "You have " + itemSelected + " items Selected";
                }
            }
        } else {
            var imageMe = $("#" + divId).find('img').attr('src');
            document.getElementById('image00').src = imageMe;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".modal-for-image").removeClass("left-modal-image");
            }, 100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess that when you go back to page 1, you need to check in your array for selected products which feature on page 1, and set them selected again in the GUI.

Comment: **Please** can you give me the code?!

Comment: Well I can't see the structure of your HTML where you select items, and I can't seem to see the code where you add things to the array when the user make a selection, so it's not really possible to give specific code. But basically in the "success" function of your ajax call to loadData.php, loop through your array, and for each item, if it appears in the HTML of the newly loaded page, then make whatever change you need to do in the HTML to mark it as selected.

Comment: **Thank You** so much, I am appreciated for helping me